# DocuSign is removing hyperlinks in documents

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the DocuSign REST API and have noticed that DocuSign appears to remove any hyperlinks from within documents in my envelopes (both regular signing documents and supplemental documents).

I've tried supplying Word, Excel and PDF's containing hyperlinks, but in every case, the hyperlinks are removed when the envelope is created. I have tested both from the DocuSign sender view and the DocuSign signing ceremony. All hyperlinks are removed. I don't want the ability to add links to documents via the DocuSign sender view/UI just prior to sending the envelope. I need to be able to add my documents (with hyperlinks) to an envelope, and have them retained.

Does anyone know if there's a way to prevent them from being removed?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't. As part of DocuSign's security policies, all documents are `flattened.` This includes removal of hyperlinks.

Workarounds:

1. In you document, include the links as plain text. The reader can't click on them, but they can copy/paste them to their browser. You could optionally use a URL shortener. Or you could include the links as QR codes.
2. Include linked pages in your envelope as supplemental documents. (Assuming the links are to static content.)
3. If you're a developer, you could use notifications from the DocuSign webhook service to trigger your software to send a followup email to your signers that include the links.

Answer (score 1):

As Larry states, you can't maintain hyperlinks within the underlying documents during a signing session. The closest thing you can do is placing an HREF text field to create a link that overlaps the in the underlying document.

Full detail on how to do this is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-create-a-hyperlink-in-DocuSign